# How can I 'bundle' a json file into a SharePoint Framework webpart?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a large block of `JSON` I need to be available in my webpart, a 'canned' search result used when in the workbench and not connected to SharePoint.

Ideally I would like to reference it as follows:

```
const queryText = 'example';
const data = require(`json!./${queryText}.json`);
```

How do I get it packaged into the web part using `webpack`?

Comment: Does it have to be a require? Can't you merge it into your code with M4 or some Gulp plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So maybe I'm not quite reading the question correctly, but here is all I did.

1. Put a sample.json file in the src/webpart directory
2. Put `var sample:any = require('sample');`

In my code, and that populates the sample variable with the json object.

Now, in order to get this to work where you specify the name with a variable, you need to do something a little bit different.

1. Create a folder in the src/webpart directory.  Let's call it JSON
2. Stick all your json files in there
3. Load them via `var simple:any = require('json/'+ queryText);`

Webpack tries to be smart and bundle all the files it needs, but when it sees a variable rather than a literal, it doesn't really know what to bundle, so it basically bundles a bunch of stuff that it shouldn't, including stuff that isn't valid js, and your bundle is hosed.  By putting it into a folder, it scopes down the things that it adds to the bundle, and everything is good.